# How do I get the columns into an csv file with opencsv from a JSONobject in Java?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am writing a little app where I go to an api, get some json data and fill that into a csv file.

It works so far, that I get a csv file, with the correct rows, but instead of columns there are still commas in text form in file.

I am using opencsv.

```
private void writeCsv(InputStream input, String name) throws IOException {
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
        }
        JSONArray docs = new JSONArray(text.toString());
        File file=new File(name + ".csv");
        String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        BufferedReader sreader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(csv));
        String csvline;
        while ((csvline = sreader.readLine()) != null) {
            writer.writeNext(csvline);
        }
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("done");
}
```

Comment: You need to provide sample input data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add column mapping strategy.

```
ColumnPositionMappingStrategy mappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
```

check this blog for better understanding.
http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/csvtobean-and-beantocsv-example-using-opencsv/